# Mailto: links, default and webmail options

Tags: usability, email, options

Having a real hard time with my team over how to present options of how to send an email using the mailto function. We are going to offer ways to send it: via your default mail app as specified by in the browser prefs, and by webmail (gmail, yahoo, hotmail/msn)

This is a solution to a lot of the pain associated with mailto: links, but presents a new pain: choice overlord when the user is used to being presented with one call of action.

Presented solution attempts to: Present the default mailto: as a primary call to action, while presenting the webmail links as analogous options.

I've attempted: presenting the webmail links with text labels and the default as a bigger button (with "send" or "email") but members of my team are think that they should be more visually associated.

Any input would be so appreciated.

[image: Invite participants (whose email addresses will be specified with the chosen email client) using the text in the field labeled "Invitation message"]

Comment: Here is how the webmail links are to be implemented: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982702/what-is-the-format-of-compose-links-to-web-mail-clients-such-as-gmail-yahoo-mai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way of grouping the sending options, I don't think it is possible to reduce the choice overload. Even worse, I am sure many users don't realise the that outlook/hotmail/msn/livemail are all the same!

I also think you should offer the option to copy the message to the clipboard, since some users will use a mail services that you don't have listed, and may already be familiar with the routine of copying and pasting content into an email. If users choose this option - close the dialog and show them a message saying that the text has been copied to the clipboard, and they should paste it into an email and send it.

Since your many options all have the same one outcome - sending an email - you should offer them as list, all with the **same weight**. This should say to the user - you must pick one of these actions.

*Your current layout makes it look as though there are separate options that do different things, which is technically true, but to the user, the outcome of each is the same.*

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fguMue.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! A team member was professing the same: "they're the same thing, just make them all buttons" but I just wasn't seeing it. Thanks for the mockup - will try this after testing the current (pictured above) design and seeing it fail